# Helicon Ape's version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll release 6.0.3

Tags: json.net, helicontech

I discovered Helicon Ape installs an alternative version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll release 6.0.3 in the GAC that doesn't include convertors such as EntityKeyMemberConvertors and ExpandoObjectConvertor. This causes major conflicts with web applications that also use Newtonsoft.Json Version 6.0 and rely upon these convertors.

Does anyone have a clue where Helicon Ape got their adapted version of Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3 from? I can't imagine they build it themselves as this would require the orginal .snk file for signing the assembly. The source code in github only supplies a dynamic.snk which results in a different PublicKeyToken. Otherwise I could have created my own build of Newtonsoft.Json with a higher version, allowing me to overrule Helicon Ape's GAC based assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to download and upgrade to Helicon Ape build 145 that is now available: https://www.helicontech.com/ape/download.html
This build now uses different version of Json dll that will not interfere with your projects.